# Is AWS SQS Connector 1.1.0 is compatible with WSO2 EI 6.4.0?

Tags: wso2, amazon-sqs, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I just wanna to check AWS SQS Connector 1.1.0 compatibility with WSO2 EI 6.4.0.

As per [Github Documentation](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-amazonsqs) below is the compatibility matrix.

[image: github image]

But as per [WSO2 Connector Store](https://store.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/details/26e66781-8016-4105-8667-00a1e2949aac) below is the compatibility matrix.

[image: wso2 store]

Which connector should I use when working with WSO2 EI 6.4.0?

Can any WSO2 Experts clarify on the same?